# Changing The TopNavFlyouts from Left-to-right to Right-to-Left(SharePoint 2007)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007

I'm trying to customize my design by applying a new css.

Now the Top Menu Bar has flyouts. But the flyout\drop-down menu starts from the left point of the menu item and I want it to start from the right. The reason it's important to me is because rightest item has a flyout which extends the width of the whole page and it cuts through the text of each flyout item.

I found a solution which is to add min-width and width to the topNavFlyOutsItem but then it makes the links unclickable.

I use Sharepoint 2007.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot/sketch of the result?